# Why no 2 days of yom Kippur out of israel

Tags: halacha

we have 2 days of yomtov for places out of Israel

But yom Kippur is one day

Why it is closer to the beginning of the month then rosh Chodesh

Similar
[Why not two days of Rosh Hodesh, as we have two days of yontif?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57498/5120)